# How to switch between object keys and clone the previous values before adding new values in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have an object in react with each key consisting of different arrays. I want to add new values to the desired array without mutating the previous elements. I need to be able to change the target key with a variable.

```
const desiredCuisine = ?????
const valueToAdd = "Pizza"

const [cuisines, setCuisines] = useState({
french: [],
italian: [],
german: []
})

const handleClick = (desiredTargetKey) => {
setCuisines((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    desiredTargetKey: [...adToPublish.desiredTargetKey, valueToAdd],
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use it like this

```
setCuisines((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [desiredTargetKey]: [...prev[desiredTargetKey], valueToAdd],
    })
 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck for hours. Really appreciate it